# whats voltage drop on 40 yards of ws2815 leds

Tags: led-strip

We are working on a project of using ws2815 led strips and our concern is how to handle the voltage drop?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. That's likely something you'd have to ask the manufacturer, as there's no way we could tell. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 3):

You can't run 40 yards of this light type without using a feeder.

That means you need to run a parallel + and - wire and connect it to the strip at least every 5 metres (5.5 yards or 16 ft).

So the voltage drop will be decided by the size of feeder wire which you use.   You can compute that in any common [voltage drop calculator](https://www.southwire.com/calculator-vdrop).

[image]

[Src](https://vipfactoryprice.com/index.php/ws2815-led-pixel-strip-60leds-m-individual-addressable-12v-300leds-programmable-digital-light-5m.html)

Comment: you can use a buck/boost in the middle of the feeder to return the voltage to 12v, at the cost of current and a bit of heat. Don't do that for the tape itself, it will overheat, but boosting the feeder wire might be cheaper/easier than super thick cable.